# Deploying my node.js app from Github to a VPS

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, vps, digital-ocean

I have an node.js application on Github. I have never done any VPS deployment before and I am learning on the go.

I am using the VPS by Hostinger.in, the OS being used is Ubuntu 14.04. So far this is what I have done:

1. Connected to their SSH successfully from my Terminal
2. Installed node.js on the server [https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/vps/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu]
3. Installed Git on the server [https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu]

I could not find any online resources for deploying my node.js to Hostinger VPS so I am following the ones written for DigitialOcean.

The one tutorial I followed is this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511

I cloned my repository doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/myusername/node-project.git
```

and it seems it was deployed (didnt give me any errors).
All the installations I did on the server I did as the root/admin user. So far I have not created any separate user to perform any of these tasks.

The server hostname given to me is dangerous-pigs.com. Now I am assuming my node.js application is deployed, but when I go to dangerous-pigs.com it shows me server not found error.

I also installed forever for my node app and when I run

```
forever start app.js
```

it says:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /root/app.js does not exist.
```

Which means the app is either not installed or installed somewhere other than the root folder.

There is a lot going on and I am confused where to start fixing issues.

How can I deploy the app to running it on the dangerous-pigs.com?

### Update

So it seems I have to go inside the project folder in root and do the

```
npm install --production
```

after which I did

```
node app.js
```

The server seems to be running but, I can only access my application if I do to the actual IP provided by the service.

So if I type http://93.188.163.249:8000 --> that's my application.

How do I change it to point to a domain?

Comment: Did you try `forever node app.js`? Are you in the project directory (try `cd`ing into there)?

Comment: Did you do a `npm install --production` and `node app.js` as mentioned in the tutorial? And did you clone locally first, to configure the application (also as mentioned in the tutorial)?

Comment: Yes, when I do npm install --production it throws this error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'

Comment: Ok, it seems that I have to go inside the actual project folder in the root and do npm install --production, which I just did. I also did node app.js and the terminal says "the server has started" but when I go to http://www.dangerous-pigs.com/, its still showing me the server not found error.

Comment: A very detailed explanation by -  https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511. Must appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research this is what I found:

Currently by default Apache2 runs on port 80. To run nodejs on port 80 first I need to install libcap2-bin in my Ubuntu server by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
```

after which I do

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs
```

the above command works if you have a mac, for windows the command **maybe**

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/local/bin/node
```

but please confirm before doing it.

Also your nodejs server needs to be stopped before you make these changes else it will not work. In my case I had forgotten to stop my node server and kept running the sudo setcap command but it did not changed the port (for obvious reasons).

If you are using forever to run node then do:

```
forever stopall
```

Comment: Hi. Did you able to run your nodejs application on hostinger. Do you have any tutorial or anything so that i can look over ther ?

Comment: I too want to run my nodejs application on hostinger VPS but not able to start anything. Do you have any such tutorial from where It can help me.

Comment: I have created a shared google document which has documented the process. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lRtXKIL1zvy05jY6KCzDP1XENdMjyQ1FMw50BR3Ljf0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should actually leverage apache proxy. This is good tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension